# What is the error in the following program with the help of split() function?

Tags: python

This program is based on separating the items given by the user in sentence form and add it to a list using `split()` method.

```
total_list = []
billed_list = []

class Naveen:
  

  question = input('what would you like to buy : ')
  def shopping_cart(self,items):
      items = question.split()
      for item in items:
          print(item)
    

  def billed_items(self):
      for item in items:
          ask = input('do u really want '+ item+' ')
          if ask ==  'yes':
              billed_list.append(item)
          if ask == 'no':
              pass
      print(billed_list)
        
            
items = []
spacex = Naveen()
spacex.shopping_cart(items)
```

Comment: What makes you think that there is an error?

Comment: Calling `input` in the class global section is decidedly odd, and probably a bug (but we have no idea what your requirements are).

Answer (score 0):

Without any indication of what your program should do, it's not obvious that there are any bugs. But if we assume that your program is a very basic shopping cart, it has the following problems;

- The I/O should probably be handled outside the class;
- The `question` should not be a class global;
- The handling of inputs other than `"yes"` or `"no"` should be defined -- either regard everything which isn't `"yes"` as `"no"` (this is what your code currently does, but by the looks of it, by mistake), or loop until you have received either `"yes"` or `"no"` response.
- The items handled in the shopping cart should be encapsulated into the instance, not global variables.
- Probably try to give the class a descriptive name, rather than a random one.

So, perhaps something like this;

```py
class ShoppingCart:
  def __init__(self):
      self.items = []
 
  def shopping_cart(self, request):
      self.items = request.split()    

  def billed_items(self):
      billed = [] 
      for item in self.items:
          ask = input('Do you really want '+ item+'? ')
          if ask ==  'yes':
              billed.append(item)
      return billed


spacex = ShoppingCart()
spacex.shopping_cart(input("What would you like to buy? "))
to_pay = spacex.billed_list()
```

`split()` out of the box splits on whitespace, so you would input items in the form

```
carrot carrot turnip pepper
```

to produce the `items` list `['carrot', 'carrot', 'turnip', 'pepper']`

Comment: why do we use request in shopping_cart function?

Comment: Are you asking why the class doesn't do `input` itself? That makes it more reusable. But then probably `billed_items` should avoid doing I/O too.

Comment: I am asking what is the use of request as a parameter in here?

Comment: It's just a variable name, you could call it `naveen` if you wanted to (but again random names are less useful for the human reader).  The variable contains the input string from the user (but we can't call it `input` because that would shadow the built-in with the same name).  You called it `question` but the variable contains the answer, not the question. But `answer` would be a misleading name for a function which doesn't necessarily receive the input from a question.

Comment: What i understood now is that the "variable request is used to split the input that we give

Answer (score -1):

Add self in front of question and you need to use seperator inside split() function.

Please check this solution code:

```
total_list = []
billed_list = []

class Naveen:
  

  question = input('what would you like to buy : ')

  def shopping_cart(self,items):
        for item in items:
            total_list.append(item)
        print("Total List:", total_list)
    
    

  def billed_items(self, items):
      for item in items:
          ask = input('do u really want '+ item+': ')
          if ask ==  'yes':
              billed_list.append(item)
          if ask == 'no':
              pass
      print("Billed List:", billed_list)
        
            
items = []
spacex = Naveen()
items = spacex.question.split(',')
spacex.shopping_cart(items)
spacex.billed_items(items)
```

Sample Input & Output:

```
what would you like to buy : Apple,Malta
Total List: ['Apple', 'Malta']
do u really want Apple: yes
do u really want Malta: no
Billed List: ['Apple']
```

Comment: thank you for this answer...it was really helpful